# How to put .flv videos on aspx pages

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have to design a page in which I have to place few flv video files. In general under upload.aspx page I uploaded few videos which are stored under videos directory in my site. I want to put them in my videoview.aspx page. Now can anyone please help in saying how to put videos in videoview.aspx page. Just I want the code to put .flv video files in page not bothered whether it is on local or server system.

Comment: Are you talking about dynamically creating controls after the file is uploaded? Or are you talking about just the tags to embed the flash?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a player of some sort.

I recommend [Longtail's JW player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a flash video player. There are a couple of decent free ones I have used here:

- http://flowplayer.org/
- http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/